# How to display "default" selected item - Combobox C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I populated combobox using an `IEnumerable<string>Variables`.
The items are displayed correctly and allows user to select an option.

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
     x:Name="ofmvar"  IsTextSearchEnabled="True" Width="150" Margin="2,2,2,2"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}" SelectionChanged="log_SelectionChanged"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVar, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
```

Most of the time (98%) user selects one specific option from the list; lets call it **"A_Variable".** but occasionally he may select a different variable from the combobox; lets call it **"B_Variable"**.

When the program launches, he expects the combobox to display **"A_Variable"** by default as selection.. Is this possible to do?

This is how the `SelectedVar` is defined:

```
public string SelectedVar
        {
            get { return _SelectedVar; }
            set
            {
                if (_SelectedVar == value) return;
                _SelectedVar = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedVar");
            }
        }               
        public string _SelectedVar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value of the `SelectedVar` property to "A_Variable" or whatever value in the `Variables` collection that you want to select in your view model class:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Variables = new List<string> { "A_Variable", "B_Variable" };

        SelectedVar = "A_Variable"; //default selected value...
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Variables { get; private set; }

    private string _SelectedVar;
    public string SelectedVar
    {
        get { return _SelectedVar; }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedVar == value) return;
            _SelectedVar = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedVar");
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `SelectedItem` is bound to `SelectedVar` of the ViewModel, just set `SelectedVar` to the default value in the constructor of the ViewModel.

Comment: I added SelectedVar information..I need to change something here?

Comment: No. In the constructor: `SelectedVar = "A_Variable";`

Comment: I am totally lost here :( Can you please show me an example? @clcto

Comment: Please see my answer. You set the value of the SelectedVar property to the string value in Variables IEnumerable that you want to be selected by default.

Comment: @user7157732 it looks like you need an introduction to constructors, [see the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx), specifically [Using Constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) and [Instance Constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx)